# Passing Path Arguments to bash

Tags: linux, path, sbt

I have the following bash script saved as sbt.sh under a folder ~/Softwares/sbt/sbt.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
echo $@
java $SBT_OPTS -jar '$1'/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

I'm trying to call this from my .bash_profile as:

```
source ~/Softwares/sbt/sbt.sh ~/Softwares/sbt/sbt-0.13.11/bin
```

When I run the Terminal, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile $1/sbt-launch.jar
```

The question is why I'm not seeing the path that I pass in as an argument to the bash file?

EDIT: I tried to create an alias as below:

```
alias sbt='sh /Users/joe/Softwares/sbt/sbh.sh'
```

When I tried running sbt from the terminal, I get the following:

```
sh: /Users/joe/Softwares/sbt/sbh.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `'` around $1 it should substitute correctly:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
echo $@
java $SBT_OPTS -jar $1/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

However with the above the params get passed down. I want to trim the path to the sbt dir and only pass in the remaining params:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
echo $@
SBT_PATH=$1
shift
java $SBT_OPTS -jar $SBT_PATH/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```